# Error installing VEP on mac

Tags: ensembl, software-installation, vep

I have tried multiple different ways to get Ensemble's [Variant Effect Predictor](https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/index.html) (`VEP`) to properly install on my mac, but I keep getting same error.

```
In /Users/username/ensembl-vep/htslib
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
 - unpacking ./Bio/tmp/biodbhts.zip to ./Bio/tmp/
./Bio/tmp/Bio-DB-HTS-2.11 - moving files to ./biodbhts
 - making Bio::DB:HTS
clang-4.0: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=12.4'
Warning: ExtUtils::CBuilder not installed or no compiler detected
Proceeding with configuration, but compilation may fail during Build

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Bio-DB-HTS' version '2.11'
Building Bio-DB-HTS
Error: no compiler detected to compile 'lib/Bio/DB/HTS.c'.  Aborting
ERROR: Shared Bio::DB:HTS library not found
```

--> When I check for the version of clang, I always get version 12, not sure where clang-4.0 is. I think error is specifically not correct path to current version of `C++`.

Comment: Do you have xcode utilities installed on your mac? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can try and get Perl's ExUtils::Builder, described [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::CBuilder) correctly installed and working, for example

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
force install Bundle::CPAN
```

You might want to use `brew` to make the build safe.

I don't do this stuff, I use OSX, I would install ensemble's VEP via `conda`

```
conda install -c bioconda ensembl-vep
```

You might want to (good idea) create a specific environment and obviously download `Anaconda` or `miniconda`.

```
conda create --name vep
conda activate vep
```

It will work, the output is below. I didn't proceed with the installation because of the shear amount of stuff downloaded into a given conda environment.  There's everything in there but the kitchen sink, like there is `mafft`, `t-coffee`, `clustalw`, `muscle` and `clustalo` required in the download. I am honestly clueless because they are all alignment algorithms. Anyway I honestly wouldn't chase the MCPAN stuff, in this instance I definitely recommend `conda`. Finally, you honestly you don't want all this extra stuff on your hard drive when you've finished just delete the entire environment.

The final point I'd like to make is `muscle5` (which is also in there) has recently significantly been modified making all other aligners obsolete on the runtime issue, but has to be run under the `super5` mode.

```
## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/anaconda3/envs/XXX # environment was edited  out

  added / updated specs:
    - ensembl-vep


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    argtable2-2.13             |    h1de35cc_1001         2.7 MB  conda-forge
    clustalo-1.2.4             |       h9722bc1_5         331 KB  bioconda
    clustalw-2.1               |       hcd10b59_7         326 KB  bioconda
    ensembl-vep-108.2          | pl5321h4a94de4_0         3.1 MB  bioconda
    expat-2.4.9                |       he9d5cce_0         127 KB
    htslib-1.14                |       hc38c3fb_0         2.0 MB  bioconda
    libdeflate-1.7             |       h9ed2024_5          52 KB
    libgfortran-5.0.0          |11_3_0_hecd8cb5_28         142 KB
    libgfortran5-11.3.0        |      h9dfd629_28         1.4 MB
    libzlib-1.2.12             |       hfd90126_3          65 KB  conda-forge
    mafft-7.508                |       ha5712d3_0         8.7 MB  bioconda
    muscle-5.1                 |       hb339e23_1         298 KB  bioconda
    mysql-connector-c-6.1.11   |       hccea1a4_1         1.2 MB
    paml-4.9                   |       hb4d813b_6         1.2 MB  bioconda
    perl-algorithm-diff-1.1903 | pl5321hdfd78af_3          36 KB  bioconda
    perl-base-2.23             | pl5321hdfd78af_2          12 KB  bioconda
    perl-bio-asn1-entrezgene-1.73| pl5321hdfd78af_3          24 KB  bioconda
    perl-bio-coordinate-1.007001| pl5321hdfd78af_3          36 KB  bioconda
    perl-bio-db-hts-3.01       | pl5321hc7384eb_4         116 KB  bioconda
    perl-bio-featureio-1.6.905 | pl5321hdfd78af_4          41 KB  bioconda
    perl-bio-samtools-1.43     | pl5321h1f540d2_3         161 KB  bioconda
    perl-bio-tools-phylo-paml-1.7.3| pl5321hdfd78af_3          58 KB  bioconda
    perl-bio-tools-run-alignment-clustalw-1.7.4| pl5321hdfd78af_3          25 KB  bioconda
    perl-bio-tools-run-alignment-tcoffee-1.7.4| pl5321hdfd78af_5          25 KB  bioconda
    perl-bioperl-1.7.8         |       hdfd78af_0           8 KB  bioconda
    perl-bioperl-core-1.7.8    | pl5321h527b516_0         1.8 MB  bioconda
    perl-bioperl-run-1.007003  | pl5321hdfd78af_0         340 KB  bioconda
    perl-business-isbn-3.007   | pl5321hdfd78af_0          18 KB  bioconda
    perl-business-isbn-data-20210112.006| pl5321hdfd78af_0          21 KB  bioconda
    perl-capture-tiny-0.48     | pl5321hdfd78af_2          19 KB  bioconda
    perl-class-data-inheritable-0.09| pl5321hdfd78af_0          10 KB  bioconda
    perl-constant-1.33         | pl5321hdfd78af_2          12 KB  bioconda
    perl-data-dumper-2.183     | pl5321ha5712d3_1          38 KB  bioconda
    perl-dbd-mysql-4.046       | pl5321hcd10b59_4          94 KB  bioconda
    perl-dbi-1.643             | pl5321ha5712d3_1         602 KB  bioconda
    perl-devel-stacktrace-2.04 | pl5321hdfd78af_1          17 KB  bioconda
    perl-digest-hmac-1.04      | pl5321hdfd78af_0          10 KB  bioconda
    perl-digest-md5-2.58       | pl5321ha5712d3_1          18 KB  bioconda
    perl-encode-locale-1.05    | pl5321hdfd78af_7          13 KB  bioconda
    perl-exception-class-1.45  | pl5321hdfd78af_0          21 KB  bioconda
    perl-file-listing-6.15     | pl5321hdfd78af_0          14 KB  bioconda
    perl-file-slurp-tiny-0.004 | pl5321hdfd78af_2          10 KB  bioconda
    perl-file-sort-1.01        | pl5321hdfd78af_3          20 KB  bioconda
    perl-file-spec-3.48_01     | pl5321hdfd78af_2           6 KB  bioconda
    perl-getopt-long-2.54      | pl5321hdfd78af_0          31 KB  bioconda
    perl-html-parser-3.80      | pl5321hb3ea9af_0          67 KB  bioconda
    perl-html-tagset-3.20      | pl5321hdfd78af_4          14 KB  bioconda
    perl-http-cookies-6.10     | pl5321hdfd78af_0          22 KB  bioconda
    perl-http-daemon-6.14      | pl5321hdfd78af_0          20 KB  bioconda
    perl-http-date-6.05        | pl5321hdfd78af_0          13 KB  bioconda
    perl-http-message-6.36     | pl5321hdfd78af_0          54 KB  bioconda
    perl-http-negotiate-6.01   | pl5321hdfd78af_4          14 KB  bioconda
    perl-io-html-1.004         | pl5321hdfd78af_0          16 KB  bioconda
    perl-io-socket-ssl-2.074   | pl5321hdfd78af_0         162 KB  bioconda
    perl-io-string-1.08        | pl5321hdfd78af_4          12 KB  bioconda
    perl-io-tty-1.16           | pl5321ha5712d3_1          30 KB  bioconda
    perl-ipc-run-20200505.0    | pl5321hdfd78af_0          76 KB  bioconda
    perl-libwww-perl-6.67      | pl5321hdfd78af_0          97 KB  bioconda
    perl-libxml-perl-0.08      | pl5321hdfd78af_3          40 KB  bioconda
    perl-lwp-mediatypes-6.04   | pl5321hdfd78af_1          24 KB  bioconda
    perl-mime-base64-3.16      | pl5321ha5712d3_2          16 KB  bioconda
    perl-net-http-6.22         | pl5321hdfd78af_0          21 KB  bioconda
    perl-net-ssleay-1.92       | pl5321h5d619eb_1         299 KB  bioconda
    perl-ntlm-1.09             | pl5321hdfd78af_5          16 KB  bioconda
    perl-perlio-gzip-0.20      | pl5321h1f540d2_3          16 KB  bioconda
    perl-sereal-4.019          | pl5321hdfd78af_0          11 KB  bioconda
    perl-sereal-decoder-4.025  | pl5321ha5712d3_1         156 KB  bioconda
    perl-sereal-encoder-4.025  | pl5321ha5712d3_1         365 KB  bioconda
    perl-set-intervaltree-0.12 | pl5321h9722bc1_2          31 KB  bioconda
    perl-socket-2.027          | pl5321ha5712d3_3          29 KB  bioconda
    perl-sub-uplevel-0.2800    | pl5321ha5712d3_4          14 KB  bioconda
    perl-test-deep-1.130       | pl5321hdfd78af_0          37 KB  bioconda
    perl-test-differences-0.69 | pl5321hdfd78af_0          19 KB  bioconda
    perl-test-exception-0.43   | pl5321hdfd78af_3          15 KB  bioconda
    perl-test-harness-3.44     | pl5321hdfd78af_0          85 KB  bioconda
    perl-test-most-0.38        | pl5321hdfd78af_0          20 KB  bioconda
    perl-test-warn-0.36        | pl5321hdfd78af_2          14 KB  bioconda
    perl-text-csv-2.01         | pl5321hdfd78af_0          70 KB  bioconda
    perl-text-diff-1.45        | pl5321hdfd78af_1          23 KB  bioconda
    perl-time-local-1.30       | pl5321hdfd78af_0          12 KB  bioconda
    perl-timedate-2.33         | pl5321hdfd78af_2          31 KB  bioconda
    perl-tree-dag_node-1.32    | pl5321hdfd78af_0          43 KB  bioconda
    perl-try-tiny-0.31         | pl5321hdfd78af_1          19 KB  bioconda
    perl-uri-5.12              | pl5321hdfd78af_0          59 KB  bioconda
    perl-url-encode-0.03       | pl5321h527b516_0          12 KB  bioconda
    perl-www-robotrules-6.02   | pl5321hdfd78af_4          14 KB  bioconda
    perl-xml-dom-1.46          | pl5321hdfd78af_1          59 KB  bioconda
    perl-xml-dom-xpath-0.14    | pl5321hdfd78af_2          12 KB  bioconda
    perl-xml-parser-2.44       | pl5321h50c80e2_8         162 KB  bioconda
    perl-xml-regexp-0.04       | pl5321hdfd78af_3          10 KB  bioconda
    perl-xml-xpathengine-0.14  | pl5321hdfd78af_3          28 KB  bioconda
    t-coffee-11.00.8cbe486     |       h26a2512_0         1.1 MB  bioconda
    unzip-6.0                  |       h3b3adb9_0          71 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        28.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  argtable2          conda-forge/osx-64::argtable2-2.13-h1de35cc_1001
  blast              bioconda/osx-64::blast-2.12.0-h0370960_3
  clustalo           bioconda/osx-64::clustalo-1.2.4-h9722bc1_5
  clustalw           bioconda/osx-64::clustalw-2.1-hcd10b59_7
  ensembl-vep        bioconda/noarch::ensembl-vep-108.2-pl5321h4a94de4_0
  entrez-direct      bioconda/osx-64::entrez-direct-16.2-h193322a_1
  expat              pkgs/main/osx-64::expat-2.4.9-he9d5cce_0
  htslib             bioconda/osx-64::htslib-1.14-hc38c3fb_0
  libdeflate         pkgs/main/osx-64::libdeflate-1.7-h9ed2024_5
  libgfortran        pkgs/main/osx-64::libgfortran-5.0.0-11_3_0_hecd8cb5_28
  libgfortran5       pkgs/main/osx-64::libgfortran5-11.3.0-h9dfd629_28
  libidn2            pkgs/main/osx-64::libidn2-2.3.2-h9ed2024_0
  libunistring       pkgs/main/osx-64::libunistring-0.9.10-h9ed2024_0
  libzlib            conda-forge/osx-64::libzlib-1.2.12-hfd90126_3
  llvm-openmp        pkgs/main/osx-64::llvm-openmp-14.0.6-h0dcd299_0
  mafft              bioconda/osx-64::mafft-7.508-ha5712d3_0
  muscle             bioconda/osx-64::muscle-5.1-hb339e23_1
  mysql-connector-c  pkgs/main/osx-64::mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-hccea1a4_1
  paml               bioconda/osx-64::paml-4.9-hb4d813b_6
  pcre               pkgs/main/osx-64::pcre-8.45-h23ab428_0
  perl               pkgs/main/osx-64::perl-5.32.1-0_h435f0c2_perl5
  perl-algorithm-di~ bioconda/noarch::perl-algorithm-diff-1.1903-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-archive-tar   bioconda/noarch::perl-archive-tar-2.40-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-base          bioconda/noarch::perl-base-2.23-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-bio-asn1-ent~ bioconda/noarch::perl-bio-asn1-entrezgene-1.73-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-bio-coordina~ bioconda/noarch::perl-bio-coordinate-1.007001-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-bio-db-hts    bioconda/osx-64::perl-bio-db-hts-3.01-pl5321hc7384eb_4
  perl-bio-featureio bioconda/noarch::perl-bio-featureio-1.6.905-pl5321hdfd78af_4
  perl-bio-samtools  bioconda/osx-64::perl-bio-samtools-1.43-pl5321h1f540d2_3
  perl-bio-tools-ph~ bioconda/noarch::perl-bio-tools-phylo-paml-1.7.3-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-bio-tools-ru~ bioconda/noarch::perl-bio-tools-run-alignment-clustalw-1.7.4-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-bio-tools-ru~ bioconda/noarch::perl-bio-tools-run-alignment-tcoffee-1.7.4-pl5321hdfd78af_5
  perl-bioperl       bioconda/noarch::perl-bioperl-1.7.8-hdfd78af_0
  perl-bioperl-core  bioconda/osx-64::perl-bioperl-core-1.7.8-pl5321h527b516_0
  perl-bioperl-run   bioconda/noarch::perl-bioperl-run-1.007003-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-business-isbn bioconda/noarch::perl-business-isbn-3.007-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-business-isb~ bioconda/noarch::perl-business-isbn-data-20210112.006-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-capture-tiny  bioconda/noarch::perl-capture-tiny-0.48-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-carp          bioconda/noarch::perl-carp-1.38-pl5321hdfd78af_4
  perl-class-data-i~ bioconda/noarch::perl-class-data-inheritable-0.09-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-common-sense  bioconda/noarch::perl-common-sense-3.75-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-compress-raw~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-compress-raw-bzip2-2.201-pl5321h9722bc1_0
  perl-compress-raw~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-compress-raw-zlib-2.105-pl5321h9722bc1_0
  perl-constant      bioconda/noarch::perl-constant-1.33-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-data-dumper   bioconda/osx-64::perl-data-dumper-2.183-pl5321ha5712d3_1
  perl-dbd-mysql     bioconda/osx-64::perl-dbd-mysql-4.046-pl5321hcd10b59_4
  perl-dbi           bioconda/osx-64::perl-dbi-1.643-pl5321ha5712d3_1
  perl-devel-stackt~ bioconda/noarch::perl-devel-stacktrace-2.04-pl5321hdfd78af_1
  perl-digest-hmac   bioconda/noarch::perl-digest-hmac-1.04-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-digest-md5    bioconda/osx-64::perl-digest-md5-2.58-pl5321ha5712d3_1
  perl-encode        bioconda/osx-64::perl-encode-3.19-pl5321ha5712d3_1
  perl-encode-locale bioconda/noarch::perl-encode-locale-1.05-pl5321hdfd78af_7
  perl-exception-cl~ bioconda/noarch::perl-exception-class-1.45-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-exporter      bioconda/noarch::perl-exporter-5.72-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-exporter-tiny bioconda/noarch::perl-exporter-tiny-1.002002-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-extutils-mak~ conda-forge/noarch::perl-extutils-makemaker-7.64-pl5321hd8ed1ab_0
  perl-file-listing  bioconda/noarch::perl-file-listing-6.15-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-file-slurp-t~ bioconda/noarch::perl-file-slurp-tiny-0.004-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-file-sort     bioconda/noarch::perl-file-sort-1.01-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-file-spec     bioconda/noarch::perl-file-spec-3.48_01-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-getopt-long   bioconda/noarch::perl-getopt-long-2.54-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-html-parser   bioconda/osx-64::perl-html-parser-3.80-pl5321hb3ea9af_0
  perl-html-tagset   bioconda/noarch::perl-html-tagset-3.20-pl5321hdfd78af_4
  perl-http-cookies  bioconda/noarch::perl-http-cookies-6.10-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-http-daemon   bioconda/noarch::perl-http-daemon-6.14-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-http-date     bioconda/noarch::perl-http-date-6.05-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-http-message  bioconda/noarch::perl-http-message-6.36-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-http-negotia~ bioconda/noarch::perl-http-negotiate-6.01-pl5321hdfd78af_4
  perl-io-compress   bioconda/osx-64::perl-io-compress-2.201-pl5321h9722bc1_0
  perl-io-html       bioconda/noarch::perl-io-html-1.004-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-io-socket-ssl bioconda/noarch::perl-io-socket-ssl-2.074-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-io-string     bioconda/noarch::perl-io-string-1.08-pl5321hdfd78af_4
  perl-io-tty        bioconda/osx-64::perl-io-tty-1.16-pl5321ha5712d3_1
  perl-io-zlib       bioconda/noarch::perl-io-zlib-1.11-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-ipc-run       bioconda/noarch::perl-ipc-run-20200505.0-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-json          bioconda/noarch::perl-json-4.10-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-json-xs       bioconda/osx-64::perl-json-xs-2.34-pl5321hcd10b59_5
  perl-libwww-perl   bioconda/noarch::perl-libwww-perl-6.67-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-libxml-perl   bioconda/noarch::perl-libxml-perl-0.08-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-list-moreuti~ bioconda/noarch::perl-list-moreutils-0.430-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-list-moreuti~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-list-moreutils-xs-0.430-pl5321ha5712d3_1
  perl-lwp-mediatyp~ bioconda/noarch::perl-lwp-mediatypes-6.04-pl5321hdfd78af_1
  perl-mime-base64   bioconda/osx-64::perl-mime-base64-3.16-pl5321ha5712d3_2
  perl-net-http      bioconda/noarch::perl-net-http-6.22-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-net-ssleay    bioconda/osx-64::perl-net-ssleay-1.92-pl5321h5d619eb_1
  perl-ntlm          bioconda/noarch::perl-ntlm-1.09-pl5321hdfd78af_5
  perl-parent        bioconda/noarch::perl-parent-0.236-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-pathtools     bioconda/osx-64::perl-pathtools-3.75-pl5321ha5712d3_3
  perl-perlio-gzip   bioconda/osx-64::perl-perlio-gzip-0.20-pl5321h1f540d2_3
  perl-scalar-list-~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-scalar-list-utils-1.62-pl5321ha5712d3_0
  perl-sereal        bioconda/noarch::perl-sereal-4.019-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-sereal-decod~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-sereal-decoder-4.025-pl5321ha5712d3_1
  perl-sereal-encod~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-sereal-encoder-4.025-pl5321ha5712d3_1
  perl-set-interval~ bioconda/osx-64::perl-set-intervaltree-0.12-pl5321h9722bc1_2
  perl-socket        bioconda/osx-64::perl-socket-2.027-pl5321ha5712d3_3
  perl-sub-uplevel   bioconda/osx-64::perl-sub-uplevel-0.2800-pl5321ha5712d3_4
  perl-test-deep     bioconda/noarch::perl-test-deep-1.130-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-test-differe~ bioconda/noarch::perl-test-differences-0.69-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-test-excepti~ bioconda/noarch::perl-test-exception-0.43-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-test-harness  bioconda/noarch::perl-test-harness-3.44-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-test-most     bioconda/noarch::perl-test-most-0.38-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-test-warn     bioconda/noarch::perl-test-warn-0.36-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-text-csv      bioconda/noarch::perl-text-csv-2.01-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-text-diff     bioconda/noarch::perl-text-diff-1.45-pl5321hdfd78af_1
  perl-time-local    bioconda/noarch::perl-time-local-1.30-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-timedate      bioconda/noarch::perl-timedate-2.33-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-tree-dag_node bioconda/noarch::perl-tree-dag_node-1.32-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-try-tiny      bioconda/noarch::perl-try-tiny-0.31-pl5321hdfd78af_1
  perl-types-serial~ bioconda/noarch::perl-types-serialiser-1.01-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-uri           bioconda/noarch::perl-uri-5.12-pl5321hdfd78af_0
  perl-url-encode    bioconda/osx-64::perl-url-encode-0.03-pl5321h527b516_0
  perl-www-robotrul~ bioconda/noarch::perl-www-robotrules-6.02-pl5321hdfd78af_4
  perl-xml-dom       bioconda/noarch::perl-xml-dom-1.46-pl5321hdfd78af_1
  perl-xml-dom-xpath bioconda/noarch::perl-xml-dom-xpath-0.14-pl5321hdfd78af_2
  perl-xml-parser    bioconda/osx-64::perl-xml-parser-2.44-pl5321h50c80e2_8
  perl-xml-regexp    bioconda/noarch::perl-xml-regexp-0.04-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  perl-xml-xpatheng~ bioconda/noarch::perl-xml-xpathengine-0.14-pl5321hdfd78af_3
  t-coffee           bioconda/osx-64::t-coffee-11.00.8cbe486-h26a2512_0
  unzip              pkgs/main/osx-64::unzip-6.0-h3b3adb9_0
  wget               pkgs/main/osx-64::wget-1.21.3-h6dfd666_0
```

Answer (score 1):

VEP requires `gcc` and `g++` for installation<sup>[1](https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl-vep#installation-and-requirements)</sup>. Before running the build script, try setting the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to the paths of your `gcc` and `g++` compilers, respectively:

```
export CC=gcc
export CXX=g++
```

You'll need to install these compilers if they don't already exist on your system.